# Why is using TransactionScope's default constructor harmful?

Tags: c#

Why is it harmful to use `TranscationScope`'s default constructor?

Can someone point me to explanation of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read this article on the MSDN blog [using new TransactionScope() Constructor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx).

Excerpt:

> The TransactionScope’s default constructor is, for the purposes of SQL
>   Sever database programming, broken.  TransactionScope’s default
>   constructor defaults the isolation level to Serializable and the
>   timeout to 1 minute.  IMO both these settings are harmful when working
>   against SQL Server.
>
> The transaction timeout is bad because it’s obscure.  A SqlCommand
>   already has a CommandTimeout property that defaults to 30 seconds.  If
>   you explicitly extend the CommandTimeout on a SqlCommand, it’s
>   probably unexpected that your transaction would timeout before that. 
>   But at least the timeout default can be changed in your application
>   configuration file.